# How can I insert data to a table in database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, object, insert

I am looking for some examples I haven't found it yet on the internet. I can insert data to database with array but I am not sure about how to add data to database with objects.

Could you show me an example inserting data basically with object?

Comment: its same as array.Each array key is column name of table similarly each object item is column name of table.If you did with array you should able to do with object.

Comment: I will try it with object instead of array by keeping your words on my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets say you have an customer object and you want to insert the details into a billing database. in your billing model:

```
    function insertFor( $customer ) {

       // Create the data structure    
       $billing = array(
        'first' => $customer->first,
        'last' => $customer->last,
        'address' => $customer->address,
        'address2' => $customer->address2,
        'city' => $customer->city,
        'state' => $customer->state,
        'zip' => $customer->zip,

        // you can also use other things like helper functions you have created
        'inserttime' => returnMicroDate(),

       // php magic constants 
        'whatsmyname' => __FUNCTION__
     );

    // insert the array into billing table     
    $this->db->insert( 'billingtable', $billing );

    // confirm that it inserted correctly
    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' ) {
        return true ; }

    //return false if there was an error
    else {return FALSE;}

    }
```

in your controller check if the insert came back as false

```
 if( $this->billing->insertFor( $customer ) == false ){

     $this->showerror($customer) ; } 

 else{ $this->nextMethodFor($customer) ;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always start with the CodeIgniter User guide.

```
class Myclass {
    var $title = 'My Title';
    var $content = 'My Content';
    var $date = 'My Date';
}

$object = new Myclass;

$this->db->insert('mytable', $object); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, content, date) VALUES ('My Title', 'My Content', 'My Date')
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: Actually, I haven't understood it exactly on the guide. I was looking for an example with its demo page to check how it is work. But I will look at the guide again. Thanks for your comment. Have a good day! :)